# Implementing a simple Restful service to store and retrieve data using AWS API Gateway/Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I'm new to AWS, so apologies in advance if this question is missing some important considerations, or has incorrect assumptions.

But basically I want to implement a service on AWS to store and retrieve data from multiple clients, which may be Android apps, Windows applications, websites etc. The way I've considered doing this is via a RESTful service using API Gateway front end, with a Lambda back end and maybe an S3 bucket to hold the data.

The basic requirements are:
(1) Clients can publish data to the server, where it is stored, perhaps with some kind of key/value structure.
(2) Clients can retrieve said data by key.
(3) If it is possible, clients to be able to subscribe to events from the service, so that they are notified if the value of a piece of data changes. This would avoid the need to poll the service, which would presumably start racking up unnecessary charges if the data doesn't change often.

Any pointers on how to get started with this welcome!

Comment: Requirement (3) is not possible with a Lambda-based approach. There is a hard limit of 5 minutes execution time.

Comment: @BlueM so would you recommend polling for data changes? Or some other approach than Lambda? The use case would be something like in the Android Facebook app, where if you're looking at a thread, updates and new comments appear automatically without needing to refresh.

Comment: Difficult to answer – but at least polling does not conflict with the Lambda approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creating a RESTful API on top of Lambda and API Gateway is one of the main use cases for this architecture. You can think of Lambda functions as controllers with methods and API Gateway as a router that forwards requests to functions based on the URL pattern.  There are many frameworks and approaches that can help out here if you don't want to write from scratch:

Lambdasync
https://medium.com/@fredrikanderzon/create-a-rest-api-on-aws-lambda-using-lambdasync-e46c68f8043f

Serverless
https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/events/apigateway/

Swagger
https://cloudonaut.io/create-a-serverless-restful-api-with-api-gateway-swagger-lambda-and-dynamodb/

As far as event subscriptions go (requirement #3) you can model this in many datastores, certainly in a relational/SQL database, with a table like this:

`Subscription (key_of_interest, user_id, events_of_interest)`

I'm leaving out data types for you to figure out, but you get the idea hopefully. After each data modification on a particular key, see if that key is of interest in the subscription table, then wire up a response to the user's who indicated interest.  The details of this of course depend on your particular requirements. A caution though: this approach will increase the cost of data modifications because of the additional overhead needed to process subscriptions.

EDIT: One other thing I forgot. S3 is better suited for non-structured data (think 'files'). For relational databases, checkout RDS. For a simple NoSQL database you might use DynamoDB, or host your own NoSQL database of choice on an EC2 instance.

Comment: Thanks, Todd! I'll give this a try later on, but it looks like it's just what I need to get started.